# Среда разработки php для Linux

Tags: ide, php, html, css, linux

Дело вот в чем. Есть ОС - нечто рожденное от убунты. Может кто нибудь подсказать среду разработки для HTML, CSS, PHP для Linux? Желательно, чтоб проверяла наличие ошибок (подсветка синтаксиса само собой). Не советовать Эклипс. Спасибо.

И может кто нибудь посоветовать литературу, ссылки, в которых описана работа с шаблонами `*.tpl`. Не создание, а именно работа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KomodoIDE - изначально сделана для динамических языков и да PhpStorm вещь очень интересная, NetBeans и Eclipse лучше для java оставить, там они себя интереснее показывают хотя и там их JetBrains уделал.

Comment: KomodeIDE - это платная вещь, а вот KomodoEdit может быть вполне кстати.

Comment: Ой да, мы же все законопослушные)

Comment: @gympi, Вы наверное никогда не работали в крупных компаниях.

Comment: Да) не работал, поделитесь что там не так?

Comment: Там никто не пользуется ворованным софтом и за это могут даже уволить

Answer (score 4):

**Рекомендую [phpStrom](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)**.

*За удовольствие придется заплатить через 30 дней триала.*

Answer (score 3):

> > Не советовать Эклипс.

netBeans ? :)

Comment: что то подобное. но это очень "сильная" прога, что нибудь полегче

Answer (score 3):

> что нибудь полегче

[Vim](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/vim/53435/)

Если нужно что-нибудь менее "хардкорное", то [Komodo Editor](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit)

Comment: *нервно хихикает*

зы: у вима есть 2 режима работы. 1-пикать, 2-всё портить.

Comment: Просили полегче =) А что может быть легче консольного vim'а? =)

Comment: Это слишком просто - он не проверяет правильность написания кода

Comment: А вы по ссылке кликали?

> Автоидентация, проверка php скрипта на на наличие ошибок

Comment: Счас кликну. Сообще поздно было доставлено видимо

Comment: Она надеюсь бесплатна?

Comment: Komodo Editor - да. Про ссылку, я имел ввиду ссылку http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/vim/53435/ где описываются плагины к vim'у,  в т.ч. и плагины проверки на наличие ошибок PHP.

Answer (score 3):

я тоже советую JetBrains PhpStorm. Триал устанавливается на много дней, если при установке проги перевести дату на несколько лет вперед, собственно с того момента и начнется 30тидневная "халява".
А ещё есть Aptana, упомянутый уже, NetBeans, Kate и т.д.

Comment: Aptana - это тот же Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

JetBrains PhpStorm. Без вариантов. По скорости уделывает все остальные. Очень удобна.