# Среда разработки на PHP под Ubuntu

Tags: apache, linux, javascript, php, ubuntu

Здравствуйте!
В конце концов надоело править **php** и **js** файлы в ***Notepad++*** и отлаживать в ***Denwer*** - решил перейти на более родную для **Apache** и **MySQL** операционку - ***linux***. В качестве дистрибутива взял имеющийся на данный момент в наличии ***Ubuntu 10.04***.

Подскажите какую среду можно можно использовать для разработки на PHP ?
Буду очень признателен за ссылки на инструкции по развертыванию среды.

Если кто [подскажет среду под привычную Windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/180822/javascript-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-windows), то то же буду благодарен!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Среда разработки php для Linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/21007/html-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-php-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-linux)

Answer (score 3):

Я использую geany, быстрый и довольно удобный. Но кой-чего хотелось бы прикрутить, конечно.

Answer (score 3):

Вы незаслуженно забыли упомянуть Netbeans. Сам пользуюсь и вам советую не варезничать. В качестве сервера XAMPP или LAMP.