# Среда разработки на PHP под Windows

Tags: apache, windows, javascript, php, iis

Здравствуйте!
В конце концов надоело править **php** и **js** файлы в ***Notepad++*** и отлаживать в ***Denwer*** - решил, если не [перейти под Linux для разработки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/180819/javascript-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-ubuntu), то хотя бы найти удобную среду под **Windows**...

Подскажите какую среду можно можно использовать для разработки на PHP ?
Буду очень признателен за ссылки на инструкции по развертыванию среды, если она нуждается в настройке или ручном связывании с PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Codelobster!** Бесплатен, удобен, поддержка FTP, SVN, Git. Встроенные плагины для наиболее популярных фреймворков и CMS. Динамическая подсказка синтаксиса, подсветка ошибок. Отладка кода. А главное преимущество - скорость работы.

Answer (score 4):

В поисковике вводишь PHP IDE и выбираешь. Таких систем много Eclipse PDT, NetBeans, PhpStorm, Komodo и др.

[http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сравнение_IDE](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_IDE)

http://habrahabr.ru/post/134391/

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/91072/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5-ide-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-php

Answer (score 3):

Из всех IDE, которые пробовал, больше всего понравился phpStorm. Минус в том что он платный, но считаю что своих денег стоит. Хотя тестовые EAP сборки вроде как бесплатные.

Answer (score 2):

мне нравится phpDesigner, работаю в нем уже более 4-х лет, все устраивает, встроенная работа с фтп, в общем рекомендую!

Answer (score 2):

Повторяете [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/91072/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5-ide-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-php)

Comment: используйте кнопку тревоги в таких случаях

Comment: В том вопросе не было указано, что спрашивают про Windows.  
К тому же в ответу указан Vim, а на сколько я знаю - это редактор под Linux...

Comment: @GuRuZ а заглянуть на www.vim.org Заратустра не позволяет? Vim/Gvim вполне себе нормально работает и под виндами (да и под dos). (В принципе, вопрос интеграции vim и MS VS решён уже достаточно давно)

Comment: @alexlz в любом случае мне нужна если не отладка, то проверка кода на ошибки...

Comment: @GuRuZ ничего не могу сказать. Но гугл на запрос https://www.google.ru/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=vim+php+error+detection&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&redir_esc=&ei=-NTrUPnzIIfL0QWf5IAY вываливает много чего (сам, естественно, не смотрел)

Comment: sublime text 2 (установите плугин SublimeLinter и настройте его, будет проверять синтаксические ошибки сразу)

вот [тут][1] немного описано про настройку ST2 для php.


  [1]: http://urbangiraffe.com/2011/08/15/sublime-text-2-for-php/

Answer (score 1):

Чисто от MS http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/

Как вариант свежая студия для веб разработки http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/rus/products/visual-studio-express-for-web

Comment: Студию пробовал - не разобрался как проверить на наличие ошибок в коде или отладить код...  
А отладка мне нужна

Comment: посмотрите матрицу она вроде бы дружелюбнее

Answer (score 1):

> мне нравится phpDesigner, работаю в нем уже более 4-х лет, все устраивает, встроенная работа с фтп, в общем рекомендую!

У phpDesigner есть один существенный минус, он платный)))
я использую NetBeans и Notepad++ перепробовал много, но остановился на этих инструментах.
Ну а на вкус и цвет ;)

Answer (score -2):

notepad ++ лучше всего ИМХО... но это ИМХО